# How to use arithmetic shift operator in Chisel

Tags: chisel

Implementing a logical shift is easy using the << or >> operator, but what about arithmetic right shift (sign extension) how to do it in Chisel?

In Chisel cheat sheet it is mentioned that >> operator is used for arithmetic right shift which is the same as logical right shift operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the sign will be extended if the type is SInt.